# Unable to broadcast event from parent controller in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-routing, angularjs-controller

I have a two controller having parent-child relationship:

This is the route for parent controller:

```
angular.module('app')
  .config(function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('data-show', {
        url: '/data',
        templateUrl: 'app/data.html',
        controller: 'DataCtrl'
      });
  });
```

This is the HTML for parent controller:

```
<div class="block-header">
   ...
   ...
    <div ng-include="'components/child_page.html'"></div>
</div>
```

Code for parent controller:

```
angular.module('app')
  .controller('DataCtrl', function ($scope) {

      $rootScope.$broadcast('someEvent', [1,2,3]);
 });
```

The child controller is part of child_page.html page, which is included in parent page using `ng-include` tag as shown above.

This is how child controller looks:

```
angular.module('app')
    .controller('childCtrl', function ($scope) {

        $scope.$on('someEvent', function(event, mass) {
            console.log('EVENT CALLED');
        });
  });
```

HTML for child page:

```
<div ng-controller="childCtrl">
    <div id="myGrid"></div>
</div>
```

But even though I am broadcasting the event from parent controller, the event is not getting called in child page.

Comment: I would bet the reason is that the child controller is not loaded yet when the event is broadcasted - so there is noone there to listen. Adding some `console.log` in the controller functions will verify this.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos: before I broadcast the event, I am writing to console `broadcasting` & on the first line of child controller, I am writing to console `child controller is loaded`. If I check console now, I first see `broadcasting` message and then `child controller is loaded` . What do I have here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments:

> I would bet the reason is that the child controller is not loaded yet when the event is broadcasted - so there is noone there to listen.

And it seems to be verified:

> before I broadcast the event, I am writing to console "broadcasting" & on the first line of child controller, I am writing to "console child controller is loaded". If I check console now, I first see "broadcasting" message and then "child controller is loaded".

Looking at the docs of `ng-include`, it emits the `$includeContentLoaded` event when the content is loaded. So a first approach is:

```
// parent controller:
$rootScope.$on('$includeContentLoaded', function() {
    $rootScope.$broadcast('someEvent', [1,2,3]);
});
```

It could be optimized later on using the parameters of the event.

Comment: Thank you for quick help. I tried with rootScope but it did not help, instead I am now using `$timeout` to add delay for 300ms before broadcating the event. Thank you for guiding me to right direction. This issue wasted almost half of my day :(

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question, I hope it will help someone.

As suggested by `Nikos Paraskevopoulos`, the child controller was not loaded when I was trying to broadcast the event from parent controller.

So I changed the parent controller to:

```
angular.module('app')
  .controller('DataCtrl', function ($scope,$timeout) {

      $timeout(function () {
        $scope.$broadcast('someEvent', [1, 2, 3]);
      }, 300);

 });
```

I added delay of 300ms which allows child controller to get loaded.

Comment: `$timeout` is really dangerous for this - better stay away from it! Main reason: what if, for some reason, the template loads in 400ms => bug.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos: What you are saying make sense but I tried broadcating the event through rootscope and that did not worked :(

Comment: Well, it may need some tweaking; the `$includeContentLoaded` event carries the scope that was created; you may be able to use *that* scope to broadcast.